# What software(s) is used to produce such neat block diagrams?

Tags: diagram

Can anyone tell me if there is any special software used to produce such block-diagrams? I have used Visio and Simulink but none was satisfying like this one.

[image]

Comment: It is probably made with TeX

Comment: Notepad would be more universal. The equivalent is available for all common platforms.In addition most of us already can use it and there's no other obstacles than to find right words and numbers. Even that's nonexistent for those who speak, read and write perfectly some graphic programming language.

Comment: @user287001 yeah but this ones pretty easy to draw in TeX. Easier than in visio

Comment: Maybe I have missed something. Latex has sometimes had a role in drawing like here https://fineartamerica.com/featured/does-this-make-me-your-bitch-pat-byrnes.html, but TeX in general form...never seen it.

Comment: @user287001 TeX is the catch all name for the language used by latex, xetex, luatex, etc. But yes it is often used to draw, and generate, block diagrams. The good thing about tex based renders is that they make increasing complexity easier

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with MS Visio. A sample:

[image]

But do not expect it's easy. You cannot draw it by dragging symbols from preset stencils + typing texts + inserting connection lines. You must do it by using Visio like a normal vector drawing program.

That's not Visio's strong area. Visio is a tool for structured multilevel documentation. The drawing tools in Visio support it, but they are not good for arty visual designs with complex curves and rich colorings. Multilevel means that in Visio one can for ex. make clicking a block to open the internals of that block.

As well you can take Inkscape, which has better drawing tools. Visio soon runs out of steam if you need finer forms than your current diagram has.

Of course, in vector drawing programs you can build a template which contains a good collection of needed shapes and text symbols. They can be placed into a custom symbol palette (=a custom stencil in Visio). After creating it drawing is much faster.

Comment: Would there be a free software program capable of producing this image?  Are you quite certain this was made with MS Visio?

Comment: I'm not at all sure it's made with Visio. My example was drawn in Visio in 2 minutes. Inkscape is free and with it one can make drawings like this. It can be made with at least with these others: Visio, Illustrator, Affinity Designer, Corel Draw, Magix Xara. From the screenshot I definitely cannot be sure which is used. Note: I believe it's a drawing. If it is a screenshot of some complex math simulation program, then my answer is useless.

Comment: The screenshot is from a published paper. However, it is absolutely not from simulation software. I didn't expect that one can produce such diagrams with Visio, I will try my best to figure it out. At least now I know where to start!